# Aharonov-Bohm effect of doubly localized wavepacket

Tags: quantum-mechanics, berry-pancharatnam-phase, aharonov-bohm

I want to imagine an exotic situation regarding Aharonov-Bohm effect. The wavefunction $\psi$ of the electron is even ($\psi(\mathbf r) = \psi(-\mathbf r)$) and localized in two spatially separated regions. This situation is described as in the below picture:

[image]

The particle is constrained in the black wire, and the red regions are where the wavefunction is localized.

Now, we adiabatically rotate the wavefunction. Since the wavefunction is even, only $\pi$-rotation, rather than $2\pi$-rotation, is required to come back to the original place. We know that for $2\pi$-rotation in the usual situation, the Aharonov-Bohm phase is $e^{2\pi i \Phi/\Phi_0}$ where $\Phi$ is the magnetic flux inside the path and $\Phi_0$ is the flux quanta. How about this exotic case, where we did half rotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar situations have been extensively studied (theoretically and experimentally) in semiconductor Aharonov-Bohm interferometers with quantum dots in their arms. One important point is *phase rigidity*, which arises in a closed interferometer, i.e., an interferometer with only two leads (the source and the drain) - the Aharonov-Bohm oscillations become strictly symmetric due to the multiple scattering events - phenomenon more generally known as *Onsager-Büttiker relations*). This necessitates using so called *open interferometers*, i.e., the interferometers with particle losses, such as the ones in the groundbreaking papers from the Heiblum group, [here](https://www.nature.com/articles/385417a0) and [here](https://www.nature.com/articles/36057).

In other words, the Aharonov-Bohm effect in a closed ring is surprisingly different from a naive picture stemming from the two-slit thought experiment, and used in many basic discussions of the Aharonov-Bohm effect (including the original AB paper).

Now, on the top of that you artificially enforce $\psi(r)=\psi(-r)$ symmetry, which probably kills the AB altogether... but this could be checked by directly solving a 1D scattering problem on the ring.